# Change the height of fullcalendar display?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How do I change the height of the main fullcalendar and have everything else fit that calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it at the initialization of the calendar or modify it dynamically using the setter.

From the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 650
});
```

Or using the setter:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 700);
```